# Pytorch. Can autograd be used when the final tensor has more than a single value in it?

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

Can autograd be used when the final tensor has more than a single value in it?

I tried the following.

```
x = torch.tensor([4.0, 5.0], requires_grad=True)
y = x ** 2

print(y)

y.backward()
```

Throws an error

```
RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs
```

The following however works.

```
x = torch.tensor([4.0, 5.0], requires_grad=True)
y = x ** 2
y = torch.sum(y)
print(y)

y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

The output is as

```
tensor(41., grad_fn=<SumBackward0>)
tensor([ 8., 10.])
```

Am I missing something here or can I proceed with the assumption that autograd only works when the final tensor has a single value in it?

Comment: I explained it in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/73011834/18892749

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#gradients

`y.backward()` is same as `y.backward(torch.tensor(1.0))`

Usually, the output is scalar and hence the scalar is passed to backward as a default choice. However, since your output is two dimensional you should call
`y.backward(torch.tensor([1.0,1.0]))`

This will give expected results with `x.grad` being `tensor([ 8., 10.])`