# How torch.Tensor.backward() works?

Tags: pytorch, gradient, torch

I recently study Pytorch and backward function of the package.
I understood how to use it, but when I try

```
x = Variable(2*torch.ones(2, 2), requires_grad=True)
x.backward(x)
print(x.grad)
```

I expect

```
tensor([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]])
```

because it is an identity function. However, it returns

```
tensor([[2., 2.],
        [2., 2.]]).
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is what you are looking for:

Case 1: when z = 2*x**3 + x

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
x = Variable(2*torch.ones(2, 2), requires_grad=True)
z = x*x*x*2+x
z.backward(torch.ones_like(z))
print(x.grad)
```

output:

```
tensor([[25., 25.],
        [25., 25.]])
```

Case 2: when z = x*x

```
x = Variable(2*torch.ones(2, 2), requires_grad=True)
z = x*x
z.backward(torch.ones_like(z))
print(x.grad)
```

output:

```
tensor([[4., 4.],
        [4., 4.]])
```

Case 3: **when z = x (your case)**

```
x = Variable(2*torch.ones(2, 2), requires_grad=True)
z = x
z.backward(torch.ones_like(z))
print(x.grad)
```

output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]])
```

To learn more how to calculate gradient in pytorch, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54754153/autograd-grad-for-tensor-in-pytorch).

Comment: So I guess shape of tensor inside backward() specifies the shape of outputs. What is the role of is size? Just a mulplication?

Comment: That is equivalent to `dy_dx = grad(outputs=y, inputs=x, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(y))`

Comment: What you are passing above is x which is tensor([[2., 2.],
        [2., 2.]])

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how to use `tensor.backward()`. The parameter inside the `backward()` is not the x of dy/dx.

For example, if y is got from x by some operation, then `y.backward(w)`, firstly pytorch will get `l = dot(y,w)`, then calculate the `dl/dx`.
So for your code, `l = 2x` is calculated by pytorch firstly, then `dl/dx` is what your code returns.

When you do `y.backward(w)`, Just make the parameter of `backward()` full of 1s if y is not a scalar; otherwise just no parameter.

Comment: What is `dot`? torch.dot only supports 1d tesnor